# Parse JSON object string from json value

Tags: json, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I'm making a request to a request to an API and the response is a JSON object, this json object contains a string that is another json object. I'm trying to use kotlinx.serialization to handle the deserialization of this object.

I could override the deserialize functionality myself but that kind of defeats the point of using this library

I hoped something like this would have worked.

```
@Serializable
data class Foo(val data: Data)

@Serializable
data class Data(val foo: String)
```

For something like the following Object

```
{
  "data":"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
}
```

I expect to get an Object Foo with property data = Object Data with property foo = "bar"

However I get the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonArray (Kotlin reflection is not available) but found class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonLiteral (Kotlin reflection is not available)
```

Comment: Hi, @spoderbiggen you want this JSON as your model(pojo) class right?

Comment: @HappySingh yes I'm sorry if I didn't make this clear in my question

Comment: Don't be sorry. I had added my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot convert JSON data properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57114952/cannot-convert-json-data-properly)

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify how you are doing the deserialization.
To get what you expect there you would have to specify the correct serializer.

```
val expectedFoo = Json.parse(Foo.serializer(), """{"data":{"foo":"bar"}}""")
```

**Note**
In my answer I'm assuming you meant to use a slightly different example string.

In your example json string, the `data` key corresponds to a String value, not to an object.
Please see the difference between the following:

```
{
  "data":"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
}
```

```
{
  "data": { "foo": "bar" }
}
```

So, in any situation, to parse that original example you would need to use some intermediate representation and parse the string representation in between.

```
@Serializable
data class Intermediate(val data: String)
//...
val intermediateFoo = Json.parse(Intermediate.serializer(), """{"data":"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"}""")
val expectedFoo = Foo(data = Json.parse(Data.serializer(), intermediateFoo.data))
```