# Cannot convert JSON data properly

Tags: java, android, json

So i am trying to fetch some json data from this api : https://opentdb.com/api_config.php for my quiz app, by using volley library.
But the problem is , it is sometimes returning a some weird data mixed up with the actual data. [image]
You can notice '&quota' in the middle of the sentence.

However when i view it in the json viewer mode, it was gone
[image]

Even in the app it is showing the same, here is my code to convert json :

```
 String results = response.getString("results");
                    JSONArray array_1 = new JSONArray(results);
                    JSONObject obj_1 = array_1.getJSONObject(0);
                    String incorrectAnswers = obj_1.getString("incorrect_answers");
                    JSONArray array_2 = new JSONArray(incorrectAnswers);

                    correctOption = obj_1.getString("correct_answer");
                    questionText.setText(obj_1.getString("question"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting your String.

```
Html.fromHtml(obj_1.getString("question"));
```

Comment: glad you find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

" is not a valid character in JSON. You have to convert such characters yourself or use a library such as apache commons.

```
data.replace(/&quot;/g,'"')
OR
org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(data);
```

Alternatively, use a library such as gson for parsing JSON effectively. As far as I remember gson by default handles HTML encoding characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library development by Google
This [article](https://medium.com/quick-code/parsing-json-on-android-using-gson-and-volley-83d6715776f8) is helpful for using GSON